# one line loop always adding values at index zero on list

Tags: python

My need is if the loop has no value then the value has to be `0`, if there is any value then be the last value of the list collected in the loop:

```
response_json = response.json()
list_shots = response_json['content']['shotmap']['shots']
last_goal = [shot['min'] for shot in list_shots if shot['eventType'] == 'Goal']
```

Example result:

```
[15, 42, 65, 90]
```

So the final analysis would be:

```
if (len(last_goal) == 0):
    last_goal = 0
elif (len(last_goal) > 0):
    last_goal = last_goal[-1]
```

In this case the final value in `last_goal` would be:

```
90
```

Is there any way to reduce the number of lines of code needed to achieve this result?

I don't know if there's a way to set the values to be added in the same position `[0]` in the list instead of all being added in sequence.

Or is there a way to add `0` already in the initial list so that it is not necessary to use `if - elif`

Comment: If you're just looking at the last variable, you can push a 0 to the front of the list.

`last_goal` = [0] + last_goal

Comment: Hi @PatricPoitras Perfectly solves my need!

Comment: Do you need the whole list or just the last one?

Comment: Hi @KellyBundy The above comment by Patric solves it perfectly, adding the ```0``` before, I can at the end ```[-1]``` without needing ```if elif```

Comment: To answer your question @KellyBundy , I only need the last value collected by the loop, the others are unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the ternary operator:

```
last_goal = 0 if not last_goal else last_goal[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could *replace* your

```
last_goal = [shot['min'] for shot in list_shots if shot['eventType'] == 'Goal']
```

with:

```
last_goal = 0
for shot in list_shots:
    if shot['eventType'] == 'Goal':
        last_goal = shot['min']
```

More lines but shorter ones, and already gives you the last one instead of the list.

Might btw be better to search *backwards* and find the *first*.

Answer (score 1):

```py
last_goal = 0
if (len(last_goal) > 0):
    last_goal = last_goal[-1]
```

reduces the number of lines by one